# How to unit test API in Xcode that requires authenticated state?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, xcode6, xctest

I need to test API that assume you have already gone through OAuth and obtain access_token.  How do I create unit tests for such API in Xcode without having to run OAuth login first before each test?

Can I create test cases for OAuth and ensure they run first (and persist access token somewhere) before these API tests are run?

Answer (score 2):

I would think if the API belongs to you, then injecting an authentication component that can be mocked in the unit test is an appropriate design. If the API doesn't belong to you, then your unit tests only need to verify how you process the response from the API. The API itself can be mocked.